# All checkboxes values in one array

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

Want to get all selected check box values in one array. But onChange function is giving error as undefined. I have posted the full component here.

I need
checkedValues =[]`

let my imgUrls: 
imgUrls = [ "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-3","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-4","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-5","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-6"]

```js
var checkedValue =["https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-4","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-5"]`

var imgUrls = [ "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-3","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-4","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-5","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-6"]

import React from 'react';


export default class Mycomp extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.url = "https://dummyimage.com/100x100";
    this.count = 0;
    this.tempImgUrls = [];

    this.state = {
        bgColor: '#bc6666',
        textColor: '#FFFFFF',
        imgCountsStart: 0,
        imgCountsEnd: 0,
        imgUrls: [],
        showMore: false,
        slectedItems: 0,
        checkedValues: []
    }
}

bgColorhandleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        bgColor: event.target.value
    });
}
textColorhandleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        textColor: event.target.value
    });
}
imgCountsStarthandleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        imgCountsStart: event.target.value
    })
}
imgCountsEndhandleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        imgCountsEnd: event.target.value
    })
}
myhandelchange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        ischecked: true
    })
}
handleSubmit = () => {
    this.tempImgUrls = [];
    this.setState({
        imgUrls: this.tempImgUrls
    })

    this.count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.imgCountsEnd - this.state.imgCountsStart; i++) {
        let imgtextcount = parseFloat(this.count) + parseFloat(this.state.imgCountsStart)
        this.url = this.url + "/" + this.state.bgColor.slice(1) + '/' + this.state.textColor.slice(1) + '/' +
            '&text=img-' + imgtextcount
        this.count += 1;
        this.tempImgUrls.push(this.url);
        this.url = 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100';
    }
    this.setState({
        imgCountsEnd: 0
    });
    this.setState({
        imgCountsStart: 0
    });

    console.log(this.tempImgUrls)

    if (this.state.imgCountsEnd - this.state.imgCountsStart < 10) {
        this.setState({
            imgUrls: this.tempImgUrls
        })
    } else if (this.state.imgCountsEnd - this.state.imgCountsStart > 10) {
        this.setState({
            showMore: true
        })
        let tempvari = this.tempImgUrls.slice(0, 10)

        this.setState({
            imgUrls: tempvari
        })
        this.tempImgUrls = this.tempImgUrls.slice(10);
    }
} 

loadMoreImage = () => {
    this.setState({
        imgUrls: []
    })
    let tempvari2 = this.tempImgUrls.slice(0, 10);
    this.setState({
        imgUrls: tempvari2
    })
    this.tempImgUrls = this.tempImgUrls.slice(10);
    if (this.tempImgUrls.length === 0) {
        this.setState({
            showMore: false
        })
    }
}
clearAll = () => {
    this.setState({
        bgColor: '#bc6666',
        textColor: '#FFFFFF',
        imgCountsStart: 0,
        imgCountsEnd: 0,
        imgUrls: [],
        showMore: false,
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <form>
                <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label htmlFor="bgColorImg">Background Color of Image</label>
                        <input type="color" className="form-control" id="bgColorImg" placeholder="Color"
                            value={this.state.bgColor} onChange={this.bgColorhandleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label htmlFor="textColor">Color Of The Text</label>
                        <input type="color" className="form-control" id="textColor" placeholder="Input Color"
                            value={this.state.textColor} onChange={this.textColorhandleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label htmlFor="imgCountsStart">No. Of Images starting at</label>
                        <input type="number" min={0} className="form-control" id="imgCountsStart" placeholder="No of Image start"
                            value={this.state.imgCountsStart} onChange={this.imgCountsStarthandleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label htmlFor="imgCountsEnd">No. Of Images ends at</label>
                        <input type="number" min={0} className="form-control" id="imgCountsEnd" placeholder="No of Imageend "
                            value={this.state.imgCountsEnd} onChange={this.imgCountsEndhandleChange} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                    onChange={this.disableBtn} disabled={this.state.imgCountsEnd === 0 && this.state.imgCountsStart === 0}>Show Photos</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.clearAll}
                    disabled={this.state.imgUrls.length === 0} >Clear All</button>
            </form>

            {/* <div>Showing from {this.state.imgCountsStart} to {this.state.imgCountsEnd}</div> */}
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.imgUrls.map(function (name, index) {
                        return <li key={index}>
                            <input type="checkbox" id={name} name={name}/>
                            <label htmlFor={name}>
                                <img alt={name} src={name} value={name} />
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
                    
            {this.state.showMore ? <button className='btn btn-warning' onClick={this.loadMoreImage}>Load More</button> : ''}

            <button disabled={this.state.slectedItems == 0} type="button" className="btn btn-md btn-secondary"
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Your Selection
            </button>
            <div className="modal" id="myModal">
                <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h4 className="modal-title">Total Number of Selection</h4>
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            Selected Items :
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: see my solution below and let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not using an arrow-function for your `.map()` callback function, so the **`this`** keyword is not bound to that execution context. Use an arrow-function instead:

See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-glade-yfl8j

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkedValues: [],
    imgUrls: [
      "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-3",
      "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-4",
      "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-5",
      "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/bc6666/FFFFFF/&text=img-6"
    ]
  };

  funValue = e => {
    const { checkedValues } = this.state;
    let updatedCheckedValues = [];
    if (checkedValues.includes(e.target.value)) {
      updatedCheckedValues = checkedValues.filter(
        value => value !== e.target.value
      );
    } else {
      updatedCheckedValues = [...checkedValues, e.target.value];
    }

    this.setState(
      {
        checkedValues: updatedCheckedValues
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.imgUrls.map((name, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>
                <input
                  onChange={this.funValue}
                  type="checkbox"
                  id={name}
                  name={name}
                  value={name}
                />
                <label htmlFor={name}>
                  <img alt={name} src={name} value={name} />
                </label>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it was giving the same error. I have posted the full component below.

Comment: @SoubhagyaJena hmm it looks like you never updated the .map() function in your code above?

Comment: @SoubhagyaJena here's the updated sandbox as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-glade-yfl8j

Answer (score 0):

import React from 'react';

export default class Mycomp extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.url = "https://dummyimage.com/100x100";
    this.count = 0;
    this.tempImgUrls = [];

    this.state = {
        bgColor: '#bc6666',
        textColor: '#FFFFFF',
        imgCountsStart: 0,
        imgCountsEnd: 0,
        imgUrls: [],
        showMore: false,
        slectedItems: 0,
        checkedValues: []
    }
}

bgColorhandleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        bgColor: event.target.value
    });
}
textColorhandleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        textColor: event.target.value
    });
}
imgCountsStarthandleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        imgCountsStart: event.target.value
    })
}
imgCountsEndhandleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        imgCountsEnd: event.target.value
    })
}
myhandelchange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        ischecked: true
    })
}
handleSubmit = () => {
    this.tempImgUrls = [];
    this.setState({
        imgUrls: this.tempImgUrls
    })

    this.count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.imgCountsEnd - this.state.imgCountsStart; i++) {
        let imgtextcount = parseFloat(this.count) + parseFloat(this.state.imgCountsStart)
        this.url = this.url + "/" + this.state.bgColor.slice(1) + '/' + this.state.textColor.slice(1) + '/' +
            '&text=img-' + imgtextcount
        this.count += 1;
        this.tempImgUrls.push(this.url);
        this.url = 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100';
    }
    this.setState({
        imgCountsEnd: 0
    });
    this.setState({
        imgCountsStart: 0
    });

    console.log(this.tempImgUrls)

    if (this.state.imgCountsEnd - this.state.imgCountsStart < 10) {
        this.setState({
            imgUrls: this.tempImgUrls
        })
    } else if (this.state.imgCountsEnd - this.state.imgCountsStart > 10) {
        this.setState({
            showMore: true
        })
        let tempvari = this.tempImgUrls.slice(0, 10)

        this.setState({
            imgUrls: tempvari
        })
        this.tempImgUrls = this.tempImgUrls.slice(10);
    }
}
funValue = e => {
    const { checkedValues } = this.state.checkedValues;
    let updatedCheckedValues = [];
    if (checkedValues.includes(e.target.value)) {
      updatedCheckedValues = checkedValues.filter(
        value => value !== e.target.value
      );
    } else {
      updatedCheckedValues = [...checkedValues, e.target.value];
    }

    this.setState(
      {
        checkedValues: updatedCheckedValues
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  };

loadMoreImage = () => {
    this.setState({
        imgUrls: []
    })
    let tempvari2 = this.tempImgUrls.slice(0, 10);
    this.setState({
        imgUrls: tempvari2
    })
    this.tempImgUrls = this.tempImgUrls.slice(10);
    if (this.tempImgUrls.length === 0) {
        this.setState({
            showMore: false
        })
    }
}
clearAll = () => {
    this.setState({
        bgColor: '#bc6666',
        textColor: '#FFFFFF',
        imgCountsStart: 0,
        imgCountsEnd: 0,
        imgUrls: [],
        showMore: false,
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <form>
                <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label htmlFor="bgColorImg">Background Color of Image</label>
                        <input type="color" className="form-control" id="bgColorImg" placeholder="Color"
                            value={this.state.bgColor} onChange={this.bgColorhandleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label htmlFor="textColor">Color Of The Text</label>
                        <input type="color" className="form-control" id="textColor" placeholder="Input Color"
                            value={this.state.textColor} onChange={this.textColorhandleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label htmlFor="imgCountsStart">No. Of Images starting at</label>
                        <input type="number" min={0} className="form-control" id="imgCountsStart" placeholder="No of Image start"
                            value={this.state.imgCountsStart} onChange={this.imgCountsStarthandleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label htmlFor="imgCountsEnd">No. Of Images ends at</label>
                        <input type="number" min={0} className="form-control" id="imgCountsEnd" placeholder="No of Imageend "
                            value={this.state.imgCountsEnd} onChange={this.imgCountsEndhandleChange} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                    onChange={this.disableBtn} disabled={this.state.imgCountsEnd === 0 && this.state.imgCountsStart === 0}>Show Photos</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.clearAll}
                    disabled={this.state.imgUrls.length === 0} >Clear All</button>
            </form>

            {/* <div>Showing from {this.state.imgCountsStart} to {this.state.imgCountsEnd}</div> */}
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.imgUrls.map(function (name, index) {
                        return <li key={index}>
                            <input type="checkbox" id={name} name={name} onChange={this.funValue}/>
                            <label htmlFor={name}>
                                <img alt={name} src={name} value={name} />
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>

            {this.state.showMore ? <button className='btn btn-warning' onClick={this.loadMoreImage}>Load More</button> : ''}

            <button disabled={this.state.slectedItems == 0} type="button" className="btn btn-md btn-secondary"
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Your Selection
            </button>
            <div className="modal" id="myModal">
                <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h4 className="modal-title">Total Number of Selection</h4>
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            Selected Items :
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

}